# XCUITest with specific UIViewController as a root controller

Tags: ios, xcuitest

I have an app that contains (like most of them) more than 5-6 controllers pushed one after another. What I'm doing right now is writing UI tests for all my screens. First 2 screens are fairly easy to test, since all the elements I am testing are already existing on the screen, and I only need to press one button to reach 2nd screen. The issue begins when I need to test screen No 4, and test has to go trough previous 3 screens to populate all the data required to reach required screen. Is there any way for me to inject different root controller (FourthVC file), and do all the testing without having to link all previous screens?

Comment: you try to change your actual code to directly launch 4th viewController instead of navigating till that. XCUITest doest do anything regarding code. it follows whatsever is written in programming and validate that.

Comment: That is correct, but I read that you can introduce TestAppDelegate file for test target, and pass arguments on app launch. Whole procedure of that was never documented, and in theory you could pass controller name argument and in test delegate you can push different root controllers. Just need someone who already did this to confirm it.

Comment: If you use UserDefaults class, you can mock data that comes from this class. Do you use UserDefaults in your 4th screen?

Comment: I don't use it. I am using `app.launchArguments` to pass flags to app delegate from UITests.